# JavaScript calculator calculates unchecked box

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm rather new to javascript and i'm trying to make a calculator that instantly calculates a total price of selected products.

The calculator works fine but right now the checkbox gets calculated alongside the rest of the  products even when unchecked.
I'm trying to make it so that when it is unchecked the value is 0 and when it is checked it is 0.50.

This is what I have so far:

```
<head>        
   <style type="text/css">                                                               
        .right{
            margin-top: 10px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 45px;
            background-color: #66CCFF;
        }

        p{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function calculate() {

            var A1 = document.getElementById('Amount1').value
            var A2 = document.getElementById('Amount2').value
            var A3 = document.getElementById('Amount3').value

            var PStart  = 0;                
            var P1      = A1*1.50;
            var P2      = A2*1.00;
            var P3      = A3*1.00;
            var PTotal  = P1+P2+P3;

            var Insert  = document.getElementById("TotalPrice");
            TotalPrice.innerHTML= PTotal;
        }
   -->
   </script>
</head>

<body onload="calculate()">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Price</legend>
            <div class="FormRow">
                <label for="Amount2">Console $1,50</label>
                <input type="text" min=0 id="Amount1" name="Amount1" oninput="calculate()" />
            </div>
            <div class="FormRow">
                <label for="Amount2">Controller $1,00</label>
                <input type="text" min=0 id="Amount2" name="Amount2" oninput="calculate()" />
            </div>
             <div class="FormRow">
                <label for="Amount3">Batteries? $0,50</label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="0.50" id="Amount3" name="Amount3" onchange="calculate()"/>
            </div>
            <div class="right" >
                <p><b>Total price:</b></p>
                <p id="TotalPrice">

                </p>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var A1 = document.getElementById('Amount1').value
var A2 = document.getElementById('Amount2').value
var A3 = document.getElementById('Amount3').checked ?
     document.getElementById('Amount3').value : 0;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g522P/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById('Amount1').checked` to verify if the checkbox is checked. So your code would look like

```
var A1 = document.getElementById('Amount1').checked           ?
         parseFloat(document.getElementById('Amount1').value) :
         0;
var A2 = document.getElementById('Amount1').checked           ?
         parseFloat(document.getElementById('Amount1').value) :
         0;
var Total = A1 + A2;
```